# Angularjs service method not getting called, TypeError: Cannot read property '

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am new to angularJs.
I am havin problem in calling a method from service.

Here is my controller (app.js)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','NameService'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller('SmsCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicPlatform','$cordovaSms', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSms, getName) {
  console.log('enetered in ctrl');
  $scope.form={}
$scope.counter=contactCount;

$scope.doContactPicker=function() {
console.log(getName);
//$scope.answer='answer';
$scope.answer =getName.nameFetched('yatin data');

 /*$scope.$watch('answer', function() {
        document.getElementById("contactFetched").innerHTML =$scope.answer;
alert('sample alert displayed');
 });*/

};
```

I have created a basic service to just return the name passed to it as argument.
Here is my service(services.js)

```
var nameService=angular.module('NameService',[]);



nameService.service('getName',function() {
console.log("service created");
 this.nameFetched=function getUserName(c) {
console.log("inside picked contact");
    var name =c; 
    return name;
}
});
```

And finally in my view(Index.html), I am just calling the function and displaying the content with some console statements.

```
<button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="doContactPicker()">Pick Contact</button>
```

Now the error I am getting is :-

```
undefined

ionic.bundle.js:21157 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameFetched' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.doContactPicker (http://192.168.0.126:8100/js/app.js:30:23)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:4:236)
    at http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57514:9
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24673:28)
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24772:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57513:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12098:21)
    at triggerMouseEvent (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2865:7)
    at tapClick (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2854:3)
    at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (http://192.168.0.126:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2927:5)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21157ident.$get @ ionic.bundle.js:17936parent.$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24774(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:57513eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:12098triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2865tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2854tapMouseUp @ ionic.bundle.js:2927
```

undefined at the top of the error statements is for

```
console.log(getName);
```

I have checked the syntax and how to create services many times now and still not able to figure out the reason for this. Kindly help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you are not injecting `getName` service properly

Following will work

```
.controller('SmsCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicPlatform','$cordovaSms', 'getName', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSms, getName)
```

Comment: wasted one full day trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You must inject your service by name in controller at which you want to use it and the use this name as object

```
.controller('SmsCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicPlatform','$cordovaSms','getName', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSms, getName) {
    console.log(getName);
}
```